# Reading Deltafiles from Azure Datalake to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, delta-lake

I am trying to read a Delta-file into a Jupyter Notebook on a notebook that is running on local processor. I have already gained access into Azure Datalake (ADLS), but I struggle to access the Delta-file.

I read in [this article](https://pypi.org/project/delta-lake-reader/#:%7E:text=.to_pandas()-,Azure,-The%20Azure%20integration) that this method should work:

```
from deltalake import DeltaTable
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem

fs = AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name='devblobstorage',credential=credential)

df_delta = DeltaTable('path/delta/fileInQuestion.delta', file_system=fs).to_pandas()
```

But when I write this I get this error message, meaning that the `file_system` parameter doesn't exist.
Anybody know how to read deltafiles in Jupyter?

Comment: I think you forgot to paste in the error? It's not clear what the issue is. Can you please share it? Also the `fileInQuestion.delta` should be the path to the table folder, not a specific file. There is no such thing as a `.delta` file as far as Delta Lake tables go (https://delta.io/)

Comment: I have a VM that is connected to a network outside of Azure. This VM will run a python script that uses the `fileInQuestion.delta` to search for data in said network. I know that `.delta` is more of a folder than a file, and it would be much easier to use a `.parquet` file in this case, but I want to preserve the versioning and schema control that `.delta` delivers